# How to update java GUI from another Runnable class ? JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, runnable

I have two classes:
- GUI that representing the Interface of my App
- RootGraph that is Runnable

I need that a jlabel is visible until the RootGraph is Runnable, when RootGraph finish his job the jlabel have to be set to not visible.

How can I set the state of JLabel in RootGraph, knowing that the running method is not overloadable?

GUI class

```
RootGraph rg1 =new RootGraph();
            rg1.SetQuery(endpoint,comboNodoGrafoTab1);
            RootGraph rg2 =new RootGraph();
            rg2.SetQuery(endpoint,comboNodoGrafoTab2);

            Thread rt1=new Thread(rg1);
            Thread rt2=new Thread(rg2);

            rt1.start();
            rt2.start();
```

RootGraph class

```
public class RootGraph implements Runnable {
private Query_Sparql querysparql;
private JComboBox jc;

public void SetQuery(String endpoint,JComboBox jc)
{
    querysparql=new Query_Sparql();
    querysparql.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    querysparql.addSelect("g",true);
    querysparql.addWhere("GRAPH ?g {?a ?b ?c .}");
    this.jc=jc;
}

@Override
public void run(){


    jc.removeAllItems();
    querysparql.exec();
    Vector<String> ris=querysparql.returnListFromSelect("g");
    jc.addItem("Default Root Graph");
    for(int i=0;i<ris.size();i++)
    {
        jc.addItem(ris.get(i));
        System.out.println(jc.getItemAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Swing you can not invoke methods on GUI classes from other threads unless explicitly stated.

So you have to use (for instance):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
           jc.removeAllItems();
     }
}
```

If you blindly replace all your swing calls by the above it will probably work (if your threads were threadsafe to begin with), but you will get a messy code. So instead you should collect the data you want to replace your items with, and when done do a single `invokeLater()` to do all GUI changes.

For more complex interactions, you can resort to [Swing worker threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Answer (score 0):

*I need that a jlabel is visible until the RootGraph is Runnable, when RootGraph finish his job the jlabel have to be set to not visible.*

Simply set `JLabel` visible property to true before running the `RootGraph`.

Make `JLabel` visible property to false as a last statement of the `run()` method.

Refresh the Frame after `run()` method.